# Testing Safari browser with Selenium throws OutOfMemory exception

Tags: java, selenium, safari, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate testing of our application on the Safari browser however I got stucked on the `java.lang.OutOfMemory` during test run. The code is actually quite simple

```
private WebDriver getDriver() {
    if(browser.equals("safari")) { //property set by Maven
        return new SafariDriver();
    }
}
```

So this piece of code is executed and then it falls on above exception. I also have looked if anyone had a same problem and I found this issue already filled in Google [tracker](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7129) but so far nothing nobody commented it.

I also found that the older other versions of Selenium needed to install an extension to the Safari browser but I think with 2.39 this is not needed any more, right?

Comment: Is this being called in a `@BeforeClass` or something similar?

Comment: Yes, `@BeforeClass` indeed.